# How to add a text item specifically on x-axis along numerical x- axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have x-axis value (as days) range from -1 to 300, code is like this

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10),limits=c(-1,290))
```

How can I label 0 to 'Baseline', and rest value no change, only label value 0?

The plot currently is like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ann. Welcome to StackOverflow. To improve your future question, please see this thread on how to make a great reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you are seeking an answer on how to label `x=0` as `Baseline`, while the remaining `x-axis label text` should remain as they are.

Data sample

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y=sample(1:17,1000, replace=TRUE), x=sample(-1:300, 1000, replace=TRUE))
```

Gives

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y=))
```

[image]

To manually alter the `x-axis text`, you could apply `paste0`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,300,50),
                     labels = c(paste0("Baseline"), paste0(seq(50,300,50))))
```

Which gives

[image]